Product is an ambigious reference between Models.Product and...?

There is a problem when I try to fetch the data to the view by datatables I guess since products are wrongly aligned because of the controller. How can I fix it, do I need to upload additional packages? I have Core, Tools and SQL Server latest versions of packages in this project. There are too many missing outcomes in the project;however,I'd like to add my github link to let you know to find out the error better.
ProductController
using Jewelry.DataAccess.Data;
using Jewelry.DataAccess.Repository;
using Jewelry.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Jewelry.Models;
using Jewelry.Models.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.Bootstrapper;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;


namespace JewelryEcomm.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

        public ProductController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            
            List<Product> objProductList = _unitOfWork.Product.GetAll(includeProperties:"Category").ToList();

            return View(objProductList);
        }

https://github.com/LisanAlGaib96/Jewelry

maybe click on Show potential fixes?
It should give you an idea what to do.
You are using both using Jewelry.Models; and using Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.Bootstrapper;. Both namespaces have a Product class. The compiler does not know what you want. So you need to fully qualify the class name instead: List<Jewelry.Models.Product>

The products can be recognized as null as there is a problem by adding jewelry.models because datatables does not work this time. I cannot fetch the data from database as tables which is called from datatables.net . Is there any other thing that I can do?
